# How to merge two tables according to certain column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two tables here:

```
Name   age  ViehcleID
james  24   LD:DS1423
Lily   19   LD:DS1262
Ruby   29   LD:DS1462
Nam    52   LD:DS1993
Roy    26   LD:DA1423
```

table 2

```
ViehcleID    PathID
LD:DS1423    BR438
LD:DS1423    BE428
LD:DS1262    BE556
LD:DS1262    BR672
LD:DS1993    Be526
LD:DS1423    BR527
LD:DS1993    BR529
LD:DS1462    BR557
```

since there are repeated values in table 2, (i.e one `vihecleID`has two `pathID`) I want to merge these two tables ***according to `vehicleID`***. This is my desired output:

```
Name   age  ViehcleID   PathID
james  24   LD:DS1423   BR438  
james  24   LD:DS1423   BR428
Lily   19   LD:DS1262   BE556
Lily   19   LD:DS1262   BR672
Ruby   29   LD:DS1462   BR557
Nam    52   LD:DS1993   BR529
Nam    52   LD:DS1993   Be526
```

So everything according to the `VehcleID`, as long as the id appears in both table, and one `VehicleID` can have several `pathID`. New to R and anything would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Try `merge(df1, df2, by="ViehcleID")`

Comment: I think you're missing `BR527` in your expected output, is that right?

Comment: Oh this one works, thank you so much! can't believe is such simple. @AndreWildberg